# Apple M1 issue with terrafom provider

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, apple-m1

I'm new to Terraform and creating S3 buckets through Terraform. I bumped in to this issue, which has various solutions on the internet, however, none worked. Here's my problem... When I try to perform terraform init, I get this error:

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/vault...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "3.23.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/vault v3.18.0...
- Installed hashicorp/vault v3.18.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.23.0 does not have a package available for your current platform,
│ darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all providers are available for all platforms.
│ Other versions of this provider may have different platforms supported.
╵
```

So far I have realized it is something to do with my Apple M1, but I have no idea what's happening, why this issue is, and importantly how to fix it.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The terraform aws provider seems quite old, can you try with latest ones, some 5.x

Comment: 3.30 minimum https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16948